# android device monitor: what is the syntax to filter rows by multiple tags?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

When filtering LogCat in "Android Device Monitor", what is the syntax that should be used for multiple tags? For example, i would like to view all logcat occurences tagged as either "foo" or "bar", i tried `tag:foo | tag:bar` but it's didn't work

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use tag~:foo|bar. Refer: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat#negation-and-regex for using regex for such queries.